# Computing group cohomology in magma?

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, group-cohomology, magma-cas

I don't how to construct a group module in MAGMA. Can someone show me how to compute group cohomology using MAGMA?

For example, I am interested in the action of finite p-groups on abelian p-groups, and using MAGMA to study those extensions.

I tried following the instructions here: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/758

But it asked for a G-module to begin with, and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Here in the Representation Theory section you can find how to define various types of G-modules:
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/628
and then a much more in depth description working with group modules:
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/k_g_modules_and_group_representations